# VS Load testing: getting error during import of huge ltrar file from load tests

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

I've made a lot of load test runs, and exported results to ltrar file. Size of file approx. 2,5 Gb. Now when I am importing results back to Visual Studio 2013 I am getting following error:

> Could not allocate space for object
>   'dbo.LoadTestTestLog'.'PK__LoadTest__A3F1E91C0F975522' in database
>   'LoadTest2010' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk
>   space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup,
>   adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for
>   existing files in the filegroup.

Visual Studio has created DB for its results in local SQL 2008 Express (10.0.2531).
Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and which version of SQL are you using? How much data is already in the database?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013, SQL Server 2008 Express, database size 4Gb. Actually I haven't created DB, it was done somehow automatically by VS. But it's a good point from you, I think, with this strange message SQL Server tries to say that about limitation of Express Edition for DB size

Comment: Which update of the SQL? Maximum database size was 4GB then increased to 10GB. LTRAR files may hold their data in compacted form so a 2.5GB file may require several GB in the database. (Compressing LTRAR files as ZIPs is worthwhile.) See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx .

Comment: version 10.0.2531, it is SQL 2008, checked it, 10Gb is limit only for 2008 R2 for SQL 2008 - 4Gb. So it's pretty clear that problem is due to max limit, and you are right about compression

Comment: Maybe you can summarize our comments in answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fault reported in the question appears to be that too much data is already held in the SQL database to allow the LTRAR to be loaded. SQL express versions have a maximum size for the database. The solution is to delete some load test results or other files to make space.

The error message is not entirely clear about what is causing the problem - or perhaps it is too precise by naming the database area that is overfull. The message goes on to suggest "*Create disk space by deleting unneeded files ...*".

Comments added to the question say the database is SQL Server 2008 Express version 10.0.2531. This [appears to be](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.co.uk/) SP1 which was [released](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=25052) in November (or December?) 2009. A [Microsoft blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2010/04/21/database-size-limit-increased-to-10gb-in-sql-server-2008-r2-express.aspx) published in April 2010 says the maximum database size was increased from 4GB to 10GB. Comparing dates suggests SP1 has the 4GB maximum size.

Loading a LTRAR file of 2.5GB into the database can be expected to need at least 2.5GB of space. The LTRAR file may be compacted in some manner and so may need much more than 2.5GB in the database. Note that LTRAR files can be compressed significantly into ZIP files.